# Property 'showNavigationIndicators' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to add the bootstrap carousel in my home page, but I am getting the error "Property 'showNavigationArrows' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'", I am using angular 12 and installed the bootstrap using this command "ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap". Below is my package.json structure

```
dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.6",
    "@angular/localize": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "angular-gauge": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0"
}
```

my AppModule:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./components/home/home.component";
import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, SearchBarComponent, HomeComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, NgbModule],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and my style.scss
/* Importing Bootstrap SCSS file. */

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have a Look at the docs [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)

You need to import the Bootstrap Module in your AppModule:

```
import {NgbPaginationModule, NgbAlertModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [NgbPaginationModule, NgbAlertModule, ...],
})
export class YourAppModule {
}
```

And add the css/scss in your angular.json (see the documentation)

You do not necessarily need to import the scss in your global-style sheet, but if you want to use/change specific bootstrap colors or classes you could do that.

Comment: I am using ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap command, so it added directly the Bootstrap module in AppModule, then also I am getting this error.

Comment: did you check your angular.json? And can you provide your AppModule.

Comment: My app-module structure  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent,SearchBarComponent, HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule,AppRoutingModule,NgbModule,
 ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: And my angular.json   "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },

Comment: ok, which module of ng-bootstrap are you trying to use, can you provide the component where you try to use it

Comment: I am trying to use ngb-carousel of bootstrap https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples this code sniplet I am trying to add in my home component